# unix unary operator error

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to find a string in the input file path and replace it different file path if it matches.

Below is the code.

*

```
FilePath='/GAMER/WIP/Forecast'
echo $FilePath
fnd='WIP'
repl='Archive'
declare -i idx b
idx= expr index $FilePath 'Forecast'
echo $idx
if [ $idx -gt $b ]
then
   arch_dir=${FilePath/$fnd/$repl}
   echo $arch_dir

fi
```

*

echo statement properly displays the value as some number but in the if statement, I am getting unary operator error .

Can anyone please correct me where I am missing

Comment: What was `idx= expr index $FilePath 'Forecast'` supposed to be?

Comment: @muru, possibly a formatting problem with backticks

Comment: You didn't assign anything to b. You'll get a slightly better error message if you use double quotes `if [ "$idx" -gt "$b" ]`

Comment: @Muru, `idx= expr index $FilePath 'Forecast'`  is the expression to check if the string 'Forecast' is present in the variable $Filepath. something is wrong here..I am guessing...normal if statement is working but with idx in if expression is giving unary operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have not defined the `b` variable, so when you write

```
if [ $idx -gt $b ]
```

the shell sees this after expanding the variables

```
if [ 12 -gt  ]
```

Use one of these forms:

```
if [ "$idx" -gt "$b" ]    # use quotes to maintain the operators as words
if [[ $idx -gt $b ]]      # the [[ form does not require quoting
if ((idx > b))            # use arithmetic expression
```

The first form will still throw an error if `b` is unset:

```
$ declare -i idx=12 b
$ [ "$idx" -gt "$b" ] && echo yes
bash: [: : integer expression expected
$ [[ $idx -gt $b ]] && echo yes
yes
$ ((idx > b)) && echo yes
yes
```

Comment: nit: b was declared, but not initialized

Comment: Also, note that `[[ $idx > $b ]]` is also valid, and (IMO) a big reason to always prefer the older `test`.  This is not at all the right place for this discussion, and perhaps I'm ranting, but lately I've been seeing a lot of code using that construction and my intuition that there is a redirection happening is always jarred by the syntax.

Comment: Except that does lexical comparisons so "2" > "12"

Comment: Ah!  Even better reason to avoid `[[`!  I'll never understand the arguments in favor of implementing a similar syntax to avoid some minor pitfalls and confusing everyone in the process!

Comment: hi Glenn, thanks for the reply. Here my intention is to find the word 'Forecast' in the filepath variable. If that word is present , I am doing replace string.

Comment: sorry the comment got submitted without finishing.  idx expression is for checking if a string is present in the variable value and this expression is not getting a value assigned , I guess. a=10
b=20

if [ $a -eq $b ]
then
   echo "$a -eq $b : a is equal to b"
else
   echo "$a -eq $b: a is not equal to b"
fi

Comment: normal straight forward if condition is working ` a=10
b=20

if [ $a -eq $b ]
then
   echo "$a -eq $b : a is equal to b"
else
   echo "$a -eq $b: a is not equal to b"
fi`

Comment: There are easier ways to do string replacement. `%{var/Forecast/Actual} ` is one way. But the problem with your code is answered

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone who replied to my question...the issue was with index command and not keeping it in parenthesis. Syntax of [[ ]] is working but it gave new error of "missing Integer expression ". Below is the code which worked finally.

```
    fnd='WIP'
b=0
a=10
repl='Archive'
rep2=$(echo $FilePath | grep -c 'Forecast')

if [[ $rep2 -gt $b ]]
then
   arch_dir=${FilePath/$fnd/$repl}
  # echo $arch_dir
   dir=$FilePath
extn='.csv'
for file in "$dir"*FORECAST*.csv
do
  echo "$file"
  if [[ "$file" > $dir/null ]]; then
    fn=$(echo "$file"|cut -d "." -f1|rev|cut -d"/" -f1|rev)
  mv "$file" $arch_dir"$fn"_$dt$extn
  else
  echo "There are no FORECAST files in directory "$dir
fi
done
fi
```